# AWS SQS: Moving to dead letter queue when error happens in consumer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have tried using npm packages like sqs-queue-parallel & sqs-consumer for consuming messages of SQS in node

But lately I have mechanism where when error happens for a particular message while processing, it should be moved to dead letter queue

But as of now it keeps on retrying the message by maximum receive count times

Is it possible with some other npm package, were whenever an error happens it should be moved directly to dead letter queue?

Answer (score 11):

Know this is a bit late but think OP is trying to ask for a dynamic policy. I.e.:

- on normal errors -> retry as per redrive-policy.
- However, for certain failures you might know you can't recover even if you try it a hundred items. In that case -> move message directly to dead letter queue.

How to do the latter if presumably what is asked.

Answer is probably to manually copy message to deadletter queue (it behaves just like any other queue in that regard) and remove message from source queue afterwards.

Don't believe there's a 'special' way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your SQS queue to move messages to your Dead Letter Queue after any number of failed message receives between 1 and 1000.

To have a message moved to the Dead Letter Queue after only one failed receive, then modify your queue's configuration and set the "Maximum Receives" value to 1. This would be part of your queue's "Redrive Policy".

See the following AWS documentation on configuring your queue:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSDeadLetterQueue.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use a new npm for that its automatically happens when you finish dealing with a message. for example if you been using node-consumer when you finish with the message you do:

```
done() //in order to remove from queue due to for success probably
```

or

```
done(err) //in order to keep in queue
```

so now in order to move message from queue to dead letter queue you dont need to do anything else in your code but only in you sqs console manager :

1. create a new queue
2. call it dead-messages (or whatever)
3. set the "Maximum Receives" value to 1 (that means after one call to
   "done(error)" the message will removed from your queue and go to the dead queue.
4. refresh!!!!
5. go back to your source queue (original one)
6. go to configure queue
7. set retrieve policy
8. put the name that you gave to the dead letter queue

thats it! good luck and i have to say the sqs is great way to scale tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think OP is asking if there is a way to move messages to DLQ after "A SINGLE FAILURE" in processing the message. As per these 2 SQS documentations I see these 2 points:

1. if the source queue has a redrive policy with maxReceiveCount set to 5, and the consumer of the source queue receives a message 6 times without ever deleting it, Amazon SQS moves the message to the dead-letter queue (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html).
2. Maximum receives value must be between 1 and 100 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-dead-letter-queue.html)

Which means that even if you set Maximum receives value to 1, your consumer would still receive the message "AT-LEAST TWICE"

I am not able to find any solution where you can move the failed message to DLQ after a single failure. Would love to hear other people's thoughts on this